# Applying gray scale only to one background image using Multiple Backgrounds in CSS?

Tags: html, css, filter, grayscale

Is it possible having two background images make just one of them black&white on hover?

here is an example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style> 
#example1 {
  background-image: url(img1.gif), url(img2.gif);
  background-position: right bottom, left top;
  background-repeat: no-repeat, no-repeat;
  height: 100px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="example1"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

I tried to use `filter: grayscale(100%);`  but do not know how to apply it only for img1.gif but not img1.gif & img2.gif

Comment: Sorry, I'm afraid it's not possible.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? They are 2 totally different images, or one is just a greyscale of the other? If they are different images, where is the greyscale to be applied?

Comment: @FluffyKitten both are colored, one of them must turn into greyscale after hover

Comment: You might be able to do it with jQuery, or I can give you a really hack-y way to do it in CSS?

Comment: @FluffyKitten perhaps next solution is a way to go  `#example1:hover{background-image: url(img1-bw.gif), url(img2.gif); }`. I believe that it is not good idea to use javascript as it will use some processor time.

Comment: Yes I avoid JS where possible, CSS or server-side code is always my preference. I've added a CSS-only solution below that needs only the 2 colour images - i.e. you don't need to create a separate greyscale image to use. It's a bit hack-y, but it works, and because you are using the same image file there is no extra image to download.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bit hack-y but you can add an overlay that contains the "hover" photo and add the greyscale filter to it. Take a look at this example - it is just using 2 images and both are in colour.

(FYI I have specified the height & width of the div for this example, but its not necessary)

```css
#example1 {
background-image: url(https://lorempixel.com/output/nature-q-c-200-200-2.jpg), url(https://lorempixel.com/output/nature-q-c-200-200-5.jpg);
  background-position: right bottom, left top;
  background-repeat: no-repeat, no-repeat;
  height: 200px;
  width:400px;
  position:relative;
  border:1px solid #ccc;
}

#example1:hover:before {
  background-image: url(https://lorempixel.com/output/nature-q-c-200-200-5.jpg);
  background-position: left top;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  filter: grayscale(100%);
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;  
  z-index:10;
}
```

```html
<div id="example1"></div>
```

Basically, we create an absolute-positioned overlay using `before` that covers the full size of the div (no matter what size it is). This contains only the image to be "greyed out" in the same position as the main div. It is only activated on hover by using `#example1:hover:before`.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this was what you wanted, but this is what i made:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style> 
#example1  {
  background-image: url("img1.jpg"), url("img2.jpg");
  background-position: right bottom, left top;
  background-repeat: no-repeat, no-repeat;
  height: 100px;
  filter: grayscale(0%);

}
#img1:hover{
    filter: grayscale(100%);
}


</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="example1">
  <div><img src="img1.jpg" alt="" id="img1"></div>
  <div><img src="img2.jpg" alt=""></div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: unfortunately images are placed into background-image. I know this option, but it is not what I'm looking for. But thanks anyway

Comment: I haven't understand you I imagine, you want to turn img1 to greyscale when example1 element is hovered right?

Comment: yes but without using img tag. only `background-image: url("img1.jpg"), url("img2.jpg");`